# Datediff without weekends/holidays with info coming from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, datediff

The scenario is: I have a workflow in which an object passes through multiple stages until it's closed (end of process). In this case, I have a table with the unique Id of this object, the day it arrived in a given stage, and the day it left this same stage. The calculation of "total days in stage X" must NOT consider weekends and holidays (which is an info that comes from a different calendar table).

| Id | first time at stage | last time at stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-09-02 | 2021-09-09 |

So in between those dates, we have a weekend and 2 holidays here in my country, which means the proper time in stage would be 3.

In paralel, I created a table with the dates of all weekends and holidays of the year (it's just one column "date"), with the intention of basically counting the days in this table that would be in between "first time at stage" and "last time at stage", in order to subtract it from the final datediff.

So I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    first_time_stage,
    last_time_stage,
    DATE_DIFF(last_time_stage,first_time_stage,DAY) - COALESCE(
            (SELECT COUNT(1)
             FROM base_holidays_and_weekends c
                LEFT JOIN base_stage_periods p ON c.date = p.first_time_at_steage AND c.date = p.last_time_stage
                WHERE date BETWEEN first_time_stage AND last_time_stage), 0) AS time_spent_in_stage
```

Where am I getting it wrong? I assume the issue is having 2 different tables, or in the JOIN... :(

Thank you for any inputs!

Comment: The left join's `ON` statement will lead to nothing, as, of course, there are no data that exactly match these conditions. So even if you put a left join, no row from `base_stage_periods` will come (worse: you could even have another stage with matching values! Chances are poor as I would be surprised that a stage would start during an 'off' day.... but it theoretically possible), then count will probably be 0.

Comment: I was looking for a solution, and I found [this page](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/) that will certainly help you. It explains how to build some calendar table(s) to manage topics like yours, and how to deal with them.